# javascript ui framework for android

Tags: javascript, android

I knew there are js library such us jquery mobile... can be used to develop android html app.
Is there a android style javascript UI library/framework which makes the html app looks more like an android native app?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are searching for :
https://github.com/jjoe64/jquery-mobile-android-theme